# Jetty Websocket with Spring IOC

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, jetty-9

I am trying to develop a web-socket based application using jetty. I also want to use spring for IOC.

Below is my code

```
Server server = new Server(8080);

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext annotationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
annotationContext.setConfigLocation("com.test.config");

ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler();
contextHandler.setErrorHandler(null);
contextHandler.setContextPath("/");

contextHandler.addServlet(TestWebsocketServlet.class, "/");
contextHandler.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener(annotationContext));
contextHandler.setInitParameter( "contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName() );
contextHandler.setInitParameter( "contextConfigLocation", AppConfig.class.getName() );
server.setHandler(contextHandler);
```

I am not able to autowire my spring dependency in my TestWebsocketServlet class. Please suggest

Comment: Of course you aren't.. `TestWebsocketServlet` isn't managed by spring so how should it be able to inject anything into.

Comment: Can we link these two context so that Bean injection is completely managed by Spring?

Comment: Use Springs web socket support is probably easier or you need to do manually wiring in your servlet